# Can you use the occupational expertise die to represent non-occupation-related experience?

Tags: cthulhu-dark

In [Cthulhu Dark](http://catchyourhare.com/files/Cthulhu%20Dark.pdf), when you roll to find out how well you do, you roll:

> - One die if the task is within human capabilities.
> - One die if it’s within your occupational expertise.
> - Your Insanity die, if you will risk your sanity to succeed.

In a game I am currently running, the characters are trying to do something that doesn’t exactly fall under any of their occupational expertises (sneaking into the third floor of a house from outside on the ground floor). The character that is doing the sneaking is a con-man specializing in taxidermy, which doesn’t specifically suggest “breaking and entering”, but someone suggested that he did it in the past.

I allowed him to use the occupational expertise die, since it seemed like it would work to represent having prior experience with it, but I’m curious whether I’m correct in using it to represent prior experience that wasn’t directly connected with the character’s occupation.

**Can you use the occupational expertise die to represent prior, non-occupation-related, experience when rolling to see how well you do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Director is encouraged to blur the lines for narrow occupations.

> Investigators with highly specific occupations (e.g. "quantum physicist" or "florist") may sometimes get the Occupation Die for things indirectly related to their occupation.
>
> -- "Cthulhu Dark", p.17

This exists so that people who pick narrow occupations, and "taxidermist con artist" probably qualifies, can still be interesting and colorful without being denied the occupation die outside those interesting and colorful specifics.

In this case your group even expects the con artist to have a more general criminal past that allows for things like breaking and entering, so go for it.